# Не сортируется по отзывам(sortReview)

Tags: javascript

```js
const qqq = [{
    name: `Alina`,
    price: `priceless`,
    review: 0
  },
  {
    name: `Oksana`,
    price: `333qwe`,
    review: 555
  },
  {
    name: `lera`,
    price: `222qwe`,
    review: {
      newUan: `2 444`
    }
  }
]

function sortByPrice(qqq) {
  const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(qqq))
  temp.forEach(element => {
    element.price = +element.price.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });

  temp.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)

  document.querySelector(`.result`).innerHTML = ''
  temp.forEach(item => {
    document.querySelector(`.result`).innerHTML += `
      <h3 >${item.name}</h3>
      <div>Цена: ${item.price}</div>
    `
  })
}

function sortReview(qqq) {
  const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(qqq))
  temp.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof(item.review) === `string`) {
      item.review = +item.review.replace(/\D/g, '')
    } else {
      item.review = item.review.newUan.replace(/\D/g, '')
    }
  })
  temp.sort((a, b) => a.review > b.review ? 1 : -1)
  document.querySelector(`.result`).innerHTML = ''
  temp.forEach(item => {
    document.querySelector(`.result`).innerHTML += `
    <h3>${item.name}</h3>
     <div>Цена: ${item.price}</div>
    <div>Отзывы: ${item.review}</div>
    `
  })
}
document.querySelector(`.review`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  sortReview(qqq)
})
document.querySelector(`.feed`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  sortByPrice(qqq)
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="result"></div>
  <button class="review">Отсортировать по отзывам</button>
  <button class="feed">Отсортирвать по цене(руб)</button>
</body>
```

Не сортируется по второй функции (sortReview). Первая работает исправно.

Comment: А вы вот этим `temp.forEach` Чего хотите достичь?

Comment: Интересно, это что за список, где Лера 200 стоит, Оксанна - 300, а Алина вообще бесценна? 

Comment: @eccs0103 Даже не обратил внимание )))) Боюсь предположить, кому мы тут помогаем.... Пусть это будут просто названия кукол из магазина детских игрушек

Comment: ХАХАХА,. Я и забыл. По приколу просто написал.

Comment: Спасибо, ребят. Нашел ошибку. Если интересно, в начальном массиве, нужно было  все цифры взять в кавычки, чтобы они считались строчными. Т.к в ф-ции(sortReview) сравнение было строго со строчкой.